# ImproperlyConfigured about template in django project

Tags: django-templates

When I am trying to access my django site, it appeared the ImproperlyConfigured error say that "Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader".

I use Bitnami Django Stack and this is not the first time I installed it, so I think that there is the conflict between the old and new one somehow. I tried to clean the previous installation many times but it still be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to run the site on an older Django version.

In the settings.py file try 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source' instead of 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader'. The Loader name was changed in more recent versions.